# i have syntax error in export keyword my nodejs code

Tags: node.js, socket.io

when i try to use command node file.js terminal show syntax error 
in this line {export default function}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

```
         const io = require('socket.io-client')
        var os = require("os");
        export default function () {
            const socket = io.connect('http://' + os.hostname() + ':3000')

            function registerHandler(onMessageReceived) {
                socket.on('message', onMessageReceived)
            }

            function getAvailableUsers(cb) {
                socket.emit('availableUsers', null, cb)
            }

            return {

                getAvailableUsers,
                registerHandler
            }
        }
```

here is my code any help if i remove export i have the same error with default keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Most likely your Node project is not setup to use ES6 module loading.

Complete response here [export default routes; SyntaxError in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243635/export-default-routes-syntaxerror-in-nodejs)

Try yo use the `module.exports` syntax as described here [module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6)